# Get new data when user swipe react-native

Tags: react-native

So I'm making an app in react-native where the user can access to a list of users. He can access to the profile page of the user that he has chosen where he will find his name, a little description and more. So I'm looking for a way to display the next user and the previous user when we swipe right or left. Is it possible ? For now, I have only the user profile.

```
 _displayDetailForUser = (idUser, name, photo, age, pratique, description, distance, connected, position, principale ) => {
    console.log("Display user with id " + idUser);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('UserProfil',  { idUser: idUser, name:name, photo: photo, age:age, pratique:pratique, description:description, distance:distance, connected:connected, position:position, principale:principale });
  }

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.view_container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.photo}>
            <ImageBackground source={{uri:this.props.navigation.getParam('photo')}} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
              <View style={styles.photo_content}>
                <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)']} style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, height: 80 }} />
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 50, color:'white' }}>{this.props.navigation.getParam('age')}</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ marginRight: 7, marginLeft: 7, backgroundColor: '#ffffff', width: 2, height: 30 }}></View>
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex:1 }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '600', color:'white' }}>{this.props.navigation.getParam('name')}</Text>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                      <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color:'white' }}>{this.props.navigation.getParam('distance')}</Text>
                      <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color:'white'}}>{this.props.navigation.getParam('pratique')}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>

              <TouchableOpacity style = {{position:'absolute', aspectRatio:0.6, resizeMode:'contain', height:50, width:50, right:10, top:10}} onPress = {()=> Alert.alert("Chat")}>
                <Image style = {{resizeMode:'contain', height:60, width:60, right:10, top:10}} source = {require("../Images/chat-bg.png")}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </ImageBackground>
          </View>    
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: You can use `react-native-swipe-gestures`

Comment: But how can I link the next view to the next profile ?